# Can I get a code page from a language preference?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, localization, locale

Windows seems to keep track of at least four dimensions of "current locale":
http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/01/364707.aspx

- DEFAULT USER LOCALE
- DEFAULT SYSTEM LOCALE
- DEFAULT USER INTERFACE LANGUAGE
- DEFAULT INPUT LOCALE

My brain hurts just trying to keep track of what the hell four separate locale's are useful for...

However, I don't grok the relationship between code page and locale (or `LCID`, or Language ID), all of which appear to be different (e.g. Japanese (Japan) is LANGID = 0x411 location code 1, but the code page for Japan is 932).

***How can I configure our application to use the user's desired language as the default MBCS target when converting between Unicode and narrow strings?***

That is to say, we used to be an MBCS application.  Then we switched to Unicode.  Things work well in English, but fail in Asian languages, apparently because Windows conversion functions `WideCharToMultiByte` and `MultiByteToWideChar` take an explicit code page (not a locale ID or language ID), which can be set to `CP_ACP` (default to ANSI code page), but don't appear to have a value for "default to user's default interface language's code page".

I mean, this is some seriously convoluted twaddle.  Four separate dimensions of "current language", three different identifier types, as well as (different) string-identifiers for C library and C++ standard library.

In our previous MBCS builds, disk I/O and user I/O worked correctly: everything remained in the DEFAULT SYSTEM LOCALE (Windows XP term: "Language for non-Unicode Programs").  But now, in our UNICODE builds, everything tries to use "C" as the locale, and file I/O fails to properly transcode UNICODE to user's locale, and vice verse.

We want to have text files written out (when narrow) using the current user's language's code page.  And when read in, the current user's language's code page should be converted back to UNICODE.

Help!!!

*Clarification: I would ideally like to use the MUI language code page rather than the OS default code page.  GetACP() returns the system default code page, but I am unaware of a function that returns the user's chosen MUI language (which auto-reverts to system default if no MUI specified / installed).*

Comment: The documentation for GetACP() so far as I have been able to read says nothing about returning the 'default'.  In my experience, it returns the ID associated with the locale selected by the user in the OS.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein GetACP() is in fact documented to indicate that it doesn't follow the user's specified MUI language, and should be avoided if you wish to be MUI aware.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, specifically: "For compatibility with [MUI] edition, your application should avoid calls that depend on GetACP..."

Comment: And who's the twit that felt it necessary to down-vote the question without saying why?!  It's not useful criticism if you can't stand behind it and say what about the question is inaccurate or poorly formatted or whatever your reasoning is behind your down-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, this is what I ended up doing:

1. `#define _CONVERSION_DONT_USE_THREAD_LOCALE // force CP_ACP *not* CP_THREAD_ACP for MFC CString auto-conveters!!!`
2. In application startup, construct the desired locale: `m_locale(FStringA(".%u", GetACP()).GetString(), LC_CTYPE)`
3. force it to agree with GetACP(): `// force C++ and C libraries based on setlocale() to use system locale for narrow strings`
   `m_locale = ::std::locale::global(m_locale);    // we store the previous global so we can restore before termination to avoid memory loss`

This gives me relatively ideal use of MFC's built-in narrow<->wide conversions in CString to automatically use the user's default language when converting to or from MBCS strings for the current locale.

Note: `m_locale` is type `::std::locale`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments by Jon Trauntvein, the `GetACP` function does reflect the user's language settings in the control panel. Also, based on the link to the "sorting it all out" blog, that you provided, DEFAULT USER INTERFACE LANGUAGE is the language that the Windows user interface will use, which is not the same as the language to be used by programs.

However, if you really want to use DEFAULT USER INTERFACE LANGUAGE then you get it by calling `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` and then you can map the language id to a code page, using the following table.
[Language Identifiers and Locales](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912040.aspx)

You can also use the `GetLocaleInfo` function to do the mapping, but first you would have to convert the language id that you got from `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` into a locale id, and I think you will get the name of the code page instead of a numeric value, but you could try it and see.

Comment: Thanks, that's a bit more information, but it seems to be tied to the necessity of creating my own table of LCID or LANGID to code pages, which is a major pain, and a maintenance problem.  Seems to me that if the OS supplies a MUI edition of Windows, and the user interface to allow users to choose a language independently of the OS itself, that our software should be able to obtain the code page for that language...

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to be able to do is configure a locale object to use the currently selected locale settings, you should be able to do something like this:

```
std::locale loc = std::locale("");
```

You can also access the current code page in windows using the Win32 ::GetACP() function.  Here is an example that I implemented in a string class to append multi-byte characters to a unicode string:

```
void StrUni::append_mb(char const *buff, size_t buff_len)
{
    UINT current_code_page = ::GetACP();
    int space_needed; 

    if(buff_len == 0)
       return;
    space_needed = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
       current_code_page,
       MB_PRECOMPOSED | MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
       buff,
       buff_len,
       0,
       0);
    if(space_needed > 0)
    {
       reserve(this->buff_len + space_needed + 1);
       MultiByteToWideChar(
          current_code_page,
          MB_PRECOMPOSED | MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
          buff,
          buff_len,
          storage + this->buff_len,
          space_needed);
       this->buff_len += space_needed;
       terminate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Unfortunately, GetACP() returns the "non unicode code page", rather than "user's locale".  Hell, I'm not even certain I want "DEFAULT USER LOCALE" and not "DEFAULT SYSTEM LOCALE"?  But it's intuitive to me that if a user sets their desired interface language to be "Chinese (Taiwan)", that the narrow code files we read & write ought to be whatever code page corresponds to Chinese (Taiwan) and not, say Chinese (PRC) even though the operating system was installed from a Chinese (PRC) SKU.

Comment: But isn't the current code page what you need in order to convert a multi-byte string into unicode?  If you want the locale, construct it by passing an empty string to it as in std::locale("").  A locale covers far more than what string encoding is expected.  It also covers rules for how various things are formatted.  Further, you might want to consider using UTF-8 for character encodings when you write files.

Comment: You're probably right.  I just don't know.  Seems to me that Windows provides an independent "default user interface language" from "default system locale".  The "default user interface language" ties in to the MUI system, and makes it so that the user specifies what language (s)he wants to use when running software, independently of the OS's install media base language.  But GetACP() only returns the OS's install media base language, not the user's desired interface language.  Seems like I'm not respecting the user's desires if I don't use their desired language.

Comment: (As to using utf-8 or utf-16 files, that will be great in the future, but this software already has legacy files written in MBCS, so must be able to read said files).

Comment: I have successfully used GetACP() to get the code page when the system was with English and I configured the regional settings for Brasil (Portuguese is my only second language).  A coworker, however has also done this with an English install and a Japanese regional language setting.  I infer therefore, that this function will return the current configured language and not the install language.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CW2A() or CA2W() which will take care of the conversion for you using the current system locale (or language used for non-Unicode applications).